# Redefining interface `unknown` parameter type in concrete implementation

Tags: typescript

Why is this valid in TypeScript?

```js
interface IBob {
    foo(input: unknown): void;

}

class Bob implements IBob {
    foo(i: string): void {  // redefining `unknown` here
        console.log(i.length);
    }
}
```

Where as free functions are correctly rejected when redefining `unknown`:

```js
function foo(i: unknown): void {
    console.log(i);
}

function bar(i: string): void {
    console.log(i.length);
}

interface IFoo {
    (input: unknown): void;

}

const f: IFoo = foo;
const b: IFoo = bar;  // not allowed
/* Type '(i: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.
 * Types of parameters 'i' and 'input' are incompatible.
 * Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I'm going to take a semi-educated guess

#### Re: `IBob`

The following syntax is used for function overloading

```
(input: unknown): void;
```

So when you setup your interface, you've set it up with function overloading in mind

```
interface IBob {
    foo(input: unknown): void;
}
```

hence the following is valid Typescript

```
interface IBob {
    foo(input: unknown): void;
    foo(input: string): number;
}
```

Then we move onto your class

```
class Bob implements IBob {
    foo(i: string): void {  // redefining `unknown` here
        console.log(i.length);
    }
}
```

Since a class can expand on an interface, when we declare `foo`'s type differently to `IBob` - it's just added to the overload. If we declare `foo`'s type without allowing overloads

```
interface IBob {
    foo: (input: unknown) => void;
}
```

Typescript throws an error

#### Re: `IFoo`

`IFoo` is setup using the same function overloading style as `IBob`,

```
interface IFoo {
    (input: unknown): void;
}
```

However, this time, when we declare the variables `f` and `b` we tell Typescript that those variables will be of type `IFoo` only. *Meaning that we cannot expand on the overloads in `IFoo` further*. So naturally, `b` will throw an error. We can get this to work however, by doing the following:

```
function bar(i: unknown | string): void
```

What we can deduce from this is that the parameters of our function need to be the union of our overload.

Comment: I was today old when I learnt of constraining overloading. Thanks.